# Can I transfer files from Nikon D3400 to PC using Bluetooth?

Tags: nikon, file-transfer, snapbridge

I was able to transfer my Nikon D3400 photos to the smartphone using SnapBridge. Can I also transfer photos using Bluetooth to the PC? Or can I only doing it using an USB cable or the SD card?

Comment: Didn't see that option but there is no reason it cannot happen in the future.

Comment: Bluetooth is quite slow and it would take a long time to transfer the image. It takes about two seconds on wifi (sony a6300)

Answer (score 2):

No you'll need to use the USB Cable or SD Card as you guessed. You can review all the features of SnapBridge on Nikon's site: http://nikonimglib.com/snbr/onlinehelp/en/index.html

In theory there's no reason why Nikon couldn't come up with an app for Windows/Mac to do the same thing as is done to the smart device but so far they have no put anything out to do that.

Answer (score 0):

A good loophole is to download it on the mobile device and then back them up with Google photos, and then just hop on a computer and sign into your Google account. Bam.